# MacBook boots in safe mode upon powering it on!

Tags: macbook-pro, safe-mode

When I power on my MacBook, it boots in safe mode without me pressing or holding any keys.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: What model of MacBook? It's most likely NVRAM that needs resetting.

Comment: MacBook Air 2015

Comment: And have you tried resetting the PRAM?

Comment: Yes, I did reset NVRAM and the issue has been fixed.
Thank you!